# Possible to set Content-Disposition header from Flux<FilePart> in Multipart request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm attempting to "pass through" an upload from a controller to another server as part of a multipart request using `WebClient`. I've finally got the file upload working, but am having trouble getting the file name in a streaming fashion from the `FilePart`. I'm not sure this is even possible?

This is the piece of code that is causing the issue:

```java
private MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> getMultipartPayload(Flux<FilePart> fileUploadFlux) {
    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();

    Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = fileUploadFlux.flatMap(Part::content);

    // spring doesn't have an encoder for FilePart, so we must extract the DataBuffer
    builder.asyncPart("file", dataBufferFlux, DataBuffer.class).headers(h -> {
        // need to set content-disposition header
        // but - this doesn't work as the filename is still a flux
        h.setContentDispositionFormData("file", fileUploadFlux.map(FilePart::filename));
    });

    return builder.build();
}
```

Note that I've had to extract the `Flux<DataBuffer>` from the `Flux<FilePart>` as Spring was unable to find a writer for `FilePart` (`No suitable writer found for part: file`).

Is it possible to set the content-disposition header in this fashion?

Comment: Hello! I was wondering if you were able to figure this out and if so could you post a full solution as I am currently trying to solve a very similar problem of passing an array files using Flux<FilePart> to another server which accepts MultiPartFile. I'm finding it hard to find any information showing the format for this with webclient and your post was the closest I have gotten.